# AutoMapper - Custom Mappings

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, mapping, automapper

I am having troubles setting up a custom mapping from my DB entity to my view model using AutoMapper.

My goal is to map the **ApplicationUser** to my **ApplicationUserViewModel**.

I am returning the list of users like this:

```
return View(Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<ApplicationUserViewModel>>(_userRepository.GetAllUsersWithRoles()));
```

In the Startup.cs my AutoMapper configuration includes the below:

```
Mapper.Initialize(config =>
{
   ...
   config.CreateMap<ApplicationUserViewModel, ApplicationUser>().ReverseMap();
});
```

And I basically want to tell AutoMapper to automatically set the below property of my ViewModel class (IsConnectedToFacebook) to true if the ApplicationUser entity from the DB has a Login stored against it with the provider facebook. So somethink like this:

```
viewmodel.IsConnectedToFacebook = user.Logins.Any(login => login.LoginProvider == "Facebook");
```

Here the view model:

```
public class ApplicationUserViewModel
{
   ...
   public bool IsConnectedToFacebook { get; set; }
}
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Nik

Answer (score 6):

I got it working with the below:

```
config.CreateMap<ApplicationUser, ApplicationUserViewModel>()
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.IsConnectedToFacebook,
                        src => src.MapFrom(s => s.Logins.Any(login => login.LoginProvider == "Facebook")));
```